# Sorting database results by category

Tags: php, json, sorting, multidimensional-array, laravel

I have a table in my database with the fields 'Category' and 'Title'. I have multiple records with the same category but other titles. What I'd like to do is print the category once on my page then show the all the titles with the same category. 
So Something like this:

```
Category 1
Title 3(=newest)
Title 2
Title 1(=olddest)

Category 2
Title 1

Category 3
Title 3(=newest)
Title 2
Title 1(=olddest)
```

Im using the Laravel 4 framework with Eloquent. So I'm getting the result back as an JSON object.

What I have at the moment:

**view**

```
@foreach($photos as $photo)

    {{$photo->Category}}

    @foreach($photo as $category)
        {{ $photo->Title }}
    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

**Controller**

```
$photos = Photo::orderBy('Date')->get(); // Sort by so that newest photos come first per category
return View::make('myView')->with('photos', $photos);
```

When looking a bit further I came on to [array_add helper](http://laravel.com/docs/helpers) but I'm not sure if I can use it and how I really should use it.

Can someone help me achieve the result I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
$photos = Photo::orderBy('category')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
return View::make('myView')->with('photos', $photos);
```

Then

```
<?php $category = ''; ?>
@foreach($photos as $photo)

    @if($category != $photo->Category)
        {{$photo->Category}}
        <?php $category = $photo->Category; ?>
    @endif

    {{ $photo->Title }}

@endforeach
```

Comment: I can't really do that, because later I'll have to sort on date. The photos will be later be ordered on date.

Comment: You're right, I've changed the original question. Hope you still can help me with that

Comment: So you just have to order by category, first, and then created_at (descending). Just edited my answer.

Comment: Just tested it out, doesn't work completely though: I'm getting only the first category printed out and every title (even of other categories) printed 3 times. I'm looking for the bug in the code at the moment